# POpen4 error rewinding stderr

Tags: ruby

Looking to spawn a process which I can issue multiple commands to. Looking to call a bat file to set some env variables for this spawned process and then leverage those without them impacting other processes etc

Ended up at POPEN4 which seems to do exactly what I want but seeing an error when it comes to the rewind of stderr.rewind

Using the example provided by popen4 below and seeing the following output

```
C:\>ruby envread.rb
pid        : 4452
stdout     : Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\>echo hello world!
hello world!

C:\>echo ERROR!  1>&2

C:\>
stderr     : ERROR!
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/POpen4-0.1.4/lib/popen4.rb:60:in `rewind': invalid argument (Errno::EINVAL)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/POpen4-0.1.4/lib/popen4.rb:60:n `block in popen4'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-open3-19-0.0.2/lib/win32/open3.rb:6:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-open3-19-0.0.2/lib/win32/open3.rb:6:in `block in popen4'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open3.rb:208:in `popen_run'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open3.rb:90:in `popen3'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-open3-19-0.0.2/lib/win32/open3.rb:5:in `popen4'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/POpen4-0.1.4/lib/popen4.rb:48:in `popen4'
    from envread.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

So to clairfy I had to use wind32-open3-19 as I'm using ruby 1.9.

Reading the IO documentation for 1.9 it says rewind cant be used for streams? I see gems like Aruba using a rewind of stderr though...

```
> rewind → 0 click to toggle source Positions ios to the beginning of
> input, resetting lineno to zero.
> 
> f = File.new("testfile") f.readline   #=> "This is line one\n"
> f.rewind     #=> 0 f.lineno     #=> 0 f.readline   #=> "This is line
> one\n" Note that it cannot be used with streams such as pipes, ttys,
> and sockets.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: requiring 'win32/open3' and calling Open4.popen4 seemed to get me around the error but still at a loss as to why rewind fails for me